# Nextjs and Sanity IO - Bulk Image Upload?

Tags: next.js

I am new to Sanity IO and I'd like to know if its possible to bulk upload and create documents through some pre-formatted file structure.

I have a document structure that has a: product name, picture and price. Is there any way to populate a file of this structure and upload it to Sanity, as well as upload the images? Or does this have to be done one at a time using Sanity Studio?

Thanks in advance.

I haven't found a solution to this yet.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 1):

I figured out how to do this. The best way to do this is as follows:

1.Create the schema and deploy it into Sanity Studio.
2.Create some items in Sanity Studio using dummy data to populate the fields.
3.Export the data from sanity using the command: 'sanity dataset export [your-project-id]
3.open the nd.json file from the .tz and modify the file contents as you require.
4. upload the nd.json file back to sanity using the command: sanity import [filename]